# Spark Java: Cannot change driver memory

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark, memory, ram

So, I have a spark standalone cluster with 16 worker nodes and one master node. I start the cluster with "sh start-all.sh" command from the master node in spark_home/conf folder. The master node has 32Gb Ram and 14 VCPUS, while I have 16Gb Ram and 8 VCPUS per node. I also have a spring application which, when it starts(with java -jar app.jar), it initializes the spark context. The spark-env.sh file is:

```
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST='192.168.100.17'
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=14000mb 
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=1
export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS='-Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true -Dspark.worker.cleanup.interval=172800 -Dspark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=172800'
```

I do not have anything in spark-defaults.conf and the code for initializing the spark context programmatically is:

```
@Bean
public SparkSession sparksession() {
     SparkSession sp = SparkSession
             .builder()
    .master("spark://....")
    .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host","192.168.100......")
    .appName("biomet")
    .config("spark.driver.memory","20g")
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "10g")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",48) 
    .config("spark.executor.memory","7g") 
    .config("spark.sql.pivotMaxValues","50000") 
    .config("spark.sql.caseSensitive",true)
    .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath","/home/ubuntu/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/guava-16.0.1.jar")
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key","...")
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key","...")
             .getOrCreate();
     return sp;
 }
```

After all this the Environment tab of the Spark UI has spark.driver.maxResultSize   10g and spark.driver.memory 20g BUT the executors tab for the storage memory of the driver says 0.0 B / 4.3 GB.

(FYI: I used to have spark.driver.memory at 10g(programmatically set), and in the executor tab was saying 4.3Gb, but now it seems I cannot change it. But I am thinking that even if when I had it 10g, wasn't it suppose to give me more than 4.3Gb?!)

How can I change the driver memory? I tried setting it from spark-defaults.conf but nothing changed. Even if I do not set at all the driver memory(or set it to smaller than 4.3Gb) it still says 4.3Gb in executors tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you're running your application in the client mode, then [per documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment):

> Maximum heap size settings can be set with spark. driver. memory in the cluster mode and through the --driver-memory command line option in the client mode. Note: **In client mode, this config must not be set through the SparkConf directly in your application, because the driver JVM has already started at that point**.

In current case, the Spark job is submitted from the application, so the application itself is a driver, and its memory is regulated as usual for Java applications - via `-Xmx`, etc.

Comment: Yes it is in client mode. Ok, then I erased it from the SparkConf. I tried putting it in Spark-defaults.conf file but it is like it does not even read this file. From my understanding, as you also said,  I cannot set programmatically the driver memory because the JVM has already started(using the sh start-all.sh). But then how am I suppose to set the driver memory? There is only the spark-env.sh file, but there is no configuration in that file for setting the driver memory in client standalone spark cluster.

Comment: you need to start `spark-submit` with `--driver-memory` option

Comment: But I am not using spark submit anywhere...you mean just try "spark-submit --driver-memory=30g" before I use "sh start-all.sh" or start my application?

Comment: yes, use `spark-submit`. I don't know what `start-all.sh` is doing, but I suspect that it's calling `spark-submit` under the hood

Comment: yes, most likely yes, start-all starts the master and slaves using the spark-env file! The point is I can not use spark-submit to execute my spring application. The application is basically a web platform that uses spark, so I have to execute it with java -jar springApp.jar and not with spark-submit.

Comment: in that case the driver is your application that you're executing - just set `-Xmx` as usual

Comment: you are perfectly right! And I was so sure I had tried it and didnt work! Thank you very much once again! Feel free to post your answer so that I can check it as right! :)

Comment: I have a similar issue, posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66986406/spark-yarn-client-mode-1-master-4-slaves-cannot-change-driver-memory-log-fi
Can you take a look at it?